# python distutils C++ compilation

Tags: python, compiler-construction, distutils, toolchain

I am trying to build a python module for android.

While I can set a compiler with `export CC=`, I am not able to do the same for C++ compilers using `export CXX=`. It still uses the basic C compiler.

Can anyone help me to figure out how to configure the compilers while building python modules?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give other details, like file naming etc? The doc on writing `setup.py` says that (as I would expect) C++ files should be recognized if you use `.cc` or `.cpp` (I guess `.C` too) as extensions

Comment: This is strange, as the internal function distutils.sysconfig.customize_compiler does look at CXX.  Can you set DISTUTILS_DEBUG in your environment and paste the output of “python setup.py -vv build”?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some old instructions for Windows how to change the compiler

```
    Create a file called 'distutils.cfg' in "C:\Python26\Lib\distutils".
    Open it with a text editor ('notepad distutils.cfg') and fill in the following lines:

    [build]
    compiler=mingw32
```

The same should go for other platforms as well when you manage to locate distutils folder.

Howver setup.py / Python packages can do their own stuff and these must be resolved case-by-case basis.

Comment: Also cross-compiling for Android has plethora of its own problems :( I suggest you try to consult this in Android specific context.